# How to enable interaction between object in different modules

Tags: python, simpy

I am using SimPy, and I try to simulate a network.

This is my main module:

```
from SimPy.Simulation import *
import node0
import message0
import network0
reload (message0)
reload (node0)
reload(network0)
initialize()
topology=network0.Network()
activate(topology, topology.operate()) 
node1=node0.Node(1)
node1.interface.send(destination='node1')
simulate(until=25)
```

I want an object of class message, which is activated by an object of class node, to interrrupt

```
class Message(Process):
    def arrive(self, destination, myEvent=delay):

        self.destination=destination
        self.interrupt(topology)
```

an object of class    `Network (topology)`.

But I'm getting an error:

```
NameError: global name 'topology' is not defined
```

And I don't know how to make an object global. And if I type topology in python shell then it shows me object topology, so why can't message see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that your `Message` class is defined in a different module than where your `topology` variable is. So called "global" variables in Python are not really global (in the sense that there's just one global namespace), but just at the top of a specific module's namespace. So the global variable `topology` in your main module's namespace is not accessible as a global variable from a different module.

My suggestion for working around this by passing the topology value to the `Message` as a parameter to the `__init__` method. If the message is being created by something other than your own code (e.g. by your `Node` class), you might need to pass it around a bit more, so that it will be available when needed.

If that is not possible, you might be able to put the topology value in the namespace of a module that can be imported by your `Message` code. This can get messy though, as circular imports can break things if you're not careful.